# Sorting issues in yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I have json array in my db {"dashboard_layout":[10,9,4,5]}

I could able to sort items but not updating the sort values in the db.

```
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        helper: fixWidthHelper,
        axis: 'y',
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

            alert(data);
            $('h6').text(data);    // Checks to make sure that data is compiled correctly
            $('h5').text(url);     //  Checks to make sure url is compiled correctly
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                data: data,
                url: '" . Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl("/site/dashboard-block-sort") . "',                
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){ 
                 alert('hii');
                alert(data.value);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             //  alert(thrownError);
              // console.log(thrownError);

            }
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
```

In my controller

```
 public function actionDashboardBlockSort(){
     if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
        $dashboardLayout = $_POST['data'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        // check here if model is not null 
        $perferencesOther = json_decode($model->others);


        $perferencesOther->dashboard_layout = $dashboardLayout; 
        // store updated preferencves in db
        $model->others = json_encode($perferencesOther); 
        $model->save(); 

        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => true,
            'value'=>$model->others
        ]); 
    } else {
        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => false,              
        ]);
    }
}
```

is something wrong? when I `alert(data)` in view page.I am getting correct sort value like `item[]=10&item[]=9&item[]=5&item[]=4` but not able to post to the controller.

Comment: are you sure you added the correct `controller/action` for the ajax call?

Comment: @muhammad ..yes You right misspelled action name

Comment: but my data is upadting in this format {"dashboard_layout":["9","5","10","4"]..I need to update the data  {"dashboard_layout":[9,5,10,4].without quotes as a integer not string

Comment: Found it I used JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK..that solves my problem...Thank you for the response

Comment: ok it wasnt written anywhere that you are having trouble with quotes, good that you solved it

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt you be using `$_POST['item']` rather than `$_POST['data']` in your action as you are posting serialize string with array `item[]` inside `data` which is a javascript `var`.

```
public function actionDashboardBlockSort(){
     if(isset($_POST['item'])) {
        $dashboardLayout = $_POST['item'];
        $model = \app\models\UserPreferences::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id])->one();
        // check here if model is not null 
        $perferencesOther = json_decode($model->others);


        $perferencesOther->dashboard_layout = $dashboardLayout; 
        // store updated preferencves in db
        $model->others = json_encode($perferencesOther); 
        $model->save(); 

        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => true,
            'value'=>$model->others
        ]); 
    } else {
        echo Json::encode([
            'status' => false,              
        ]);
    }
}
```